# Aptitude for Busoshoku?

Tags: one-piece

My question is about busoshoku haki or coat of arms as people like to call it. Until the last episode I thought haki was something that required intensive training to master. But in the last episode

For those who haven't watched spoilers:

> Sabo was shown wielding busoshoku against a small army at 17.

Now I only started reading the manga in the zou arc so I'm not sure if this is filler or cannon but is it safe to assume then that some people just have an aptitude for mastering buso quickly? I mean only a small percentage of people are capable of using haoshoku so it seems like it makes sense.

But it took Luffy two years to perfect it and I'm not even sure if Ace ever learned it. Does anyone have any feedback on this?

Comment: Technically, sabo been training with people who use haki since he was 10, and even then he was already kicking ass and taking names. Luffy didn't even know what haki was until he was like 18. Lets say it took sabo the same amount of time that luffy took to learn how to use haki, then he'd still be 12. Its not surprising to me that he'd know how to use it by 17. I'm not sure if the manga has more details since I only watch the anime.

Comment: Ok but I have a follow-up question to go along with that. Does being able to use busoshoku automatically mean that you can use kenbunshoku? It seems like so far every character that has buso has kenbun. But I'm not 100% sure. From what I've read they are two entirely different things but only the buso requires a ton of training.

Comment: follow up questions should be asked in a new question instead of comments. Also, my best guess is that haki in general is something that's innate but can be learned. Therefor, if you're going to learn armament, it makes sense that you will also spend some time on sensory. However, users with innate sensory haki seem to be a cut above, and conquerer's haki is something you can only train (as in you can use it better if you already have it, but you can't learn if its not innate). Again, this is only from the anime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haki does require intensive training to master, but after being rescued by Dragon at the age of ten, he presumably started training with the revolutionary army shortly after his injuries healed.

At this point, Sabo wasn't just your average ten year old, having been fighting Luffy and Ace many times every day, he was already stronger than an average pirate or soldier. It seems likely that Dragon or Ivankov or another high ranking revolutionary saw his potential, and trained him specially, as by just the age of 22 he had already risen to the rank of Chief of Staff, number two in the revolutionary army.

Unlike Luffy, he was in a position where he was surrounded by strong allies who could train him and teach him useful skills like Haki and martial arts, so having learnt to use busoshoku haki effectively by seventeen isn't hard to believe. Except for in the New World, haki is a very rare skill, and considering it took Rayleigh eighteen months to teach Luffy the basics. Luffy never had anyone to teach him growing up in Fusha Village and then setting sail by himself, as you would need someone who knows haki themselves, which is rare, and is also willing to spend the time to train you.

Comment: Obviously, Garp could have taught Luffy haki if he had wanted to, but he was rarely present being an active marine, had very dubious methods of training his grandsons, and was devoting more of his energy when he did meet with Luffy and Ace to convincing them to join the marines, and knew that if they did join the marines as he expected, they would eventually be taught haki.

Comment: you should edit your answer and add your comment to it

Comment: Firstly I agree with Qiri. Secondly thats true I bet he would have if Luffy said he was fine with becomming a marine. I guess it all comes down to time and place. Can you take a look at the comment I posted under my question. Its a follow up asking about further detail.

Answer (score 1):

This matter is not mentioned specifically in the manga either, but we can make a few suppositions about it.

First, as ton.yeung mentioned in a comment, by 17 Sabo has been around people who have mastered Haki for a long time now (Dragon, Ivankov, and many more we may not yet know). Therefore, he had time to train and learned how to master it by 17.

Another thing is that we know from Rayleigh that every person is better at one type of Haki than in the other two. Luffy is better at mastering the Emperor's Haki. Sabo, who has shown incredible strength in his fingers, may be better at Busoshoku than in the other two and therefore that may explained why he was able to master it so young.

Last but not least, Ace Luffy and Sabo have shown exceptional physical and mental capabilities from a very young age. Common sense may not applied to these three.

Comment: In the manga is Ace ever shown to have haki? I've been reading since the zou arc and I haven't had a chance to go back that far. I never saw him use it in the anime. Even at Marineford and the first person who used it in the anime I think was sentomaru.